# Possible rendering issue with QScrollArea and QPainter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter, qscrollarea

I'm trying to create a character map visualization tool with PyQt5. With fontTools library, I'm extracting the UNICODE code points supported in a given ttf file. Then using `QPainter.drawText` I'm drawing the glyphs on labels. The labels are stored in a `QGridLayout` and the layout is in a `QScrollArea`

Everything works fine, except when I try to scroll. The drawn images are overlapped whenever I try to scroll too fast. It looks like this. [image: screen cap]

The labels are redrawn properly the moment the window loses focus.

Here's an MWE of what I've so far.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFontDatabase, QFont, QColor, QPainter

from fontTools.ttLib import TTFont

class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fileName = "mukti.ttf" #the ttf file is located in the same path as the script

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Glyph Viewer")
        self.setFixedSize(640, 480)
        self.move(100, 100)

        vBox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.glyphView = GlyphView()
        vBox.addWidget(self.glyphView)

        self.setLayout(vBox)

        self.showGlyphs()

        self.show()

    def showGlyphs(self):
        #Using the fontTools libray, the unicode blocks are obtained from the ttf file
        font = TTFont(self.fileName)
        charMaps = list()
        for cmap in font['cmap'].tables:
            charMaps.append(cmap.cmap)
        charMap = charMaps[0]

        fontDB = QFontDatabase()
        fontID = fontDB.addApplicationFont("mukti.ttf")
        fonts = fontDB.applicationFontFamilies(fontID)
        qFont = QFont(fonts[0])
        qFont.setPointSize(28)

        self.glyphView.populateGrid(charMap, qFont)

class GlyphView(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)

    def populateGrid(self, charMap, qFont):
        glyphArea = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        glyphArea.setLayout(gridLayout)

        row, col = 1, 1
        for char in charMap:
            uni = charMap[char]
            gridLayout.addWidget(Glyph(qFont, chr(char)), row, col)
            if not col % 4:
                col = 1
                row += 1
            else:
                col += 1

        self.setWidget(glyphArea)

class Glyph(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, font, char):
        super().__init__()
        self.font = font
        self.char = char

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(48, 48)
        self.setToolTip(self.char)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(0,0,0))
        qp.drawRect(0, 0, 48, 48)
        qp.setFont(self.font)
        qp.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 255))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, self.char)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `paintEvent()` method gives us an object that belongs to `QPaintEvent`, that object provides a `QRect` through the `rect()` method, that `QRect` is the area that is currently visible, and that information could be used to optimize the painting, for example let's say we have a widget that shows texts in several lines, if the text is large few lines will look so painting all is a waste of resources, so with a proper calculation using the aforementioned `QRect` we could get those lines and paint that part spending few resources. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460376/custom-widget-in-qscrollarea-badly-redrawing-only-on-scroll/52461619#52461619) I show an example of the use of event.rect().

In your case there is no need to use `event.rect()` since you would be painting the text in a part of the widget widget. what you should use is `self.rect()`:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    qp = QPainter(self)
    qp.setBrush(QColor(0,0,0))
    qp.drawRect(0, 0, 48, 48)
    qp.setFont(self.font())
    qp.setPen(QColor(255, 255, 255))
    # change event.rect() to self.rect()
    qp.drawText(self.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, self.text())
```

I also see unnecessary to overwrite `paintEvent()` method since you can point directly to the `QLabel` the font, the text and the alignment:

```
class Glyph(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, font, char):
        super().__init__(font=font, text=char, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter, toolTip=char)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!